# Securing Password With Login Name

Tags: security, encryption, hash, passwords

I have a question regarding using Login Names to protect passwords.

1. You salt the Login Name with a shared salt and then hash it with BCrypt.
2. You then take the original plain text Login Name and use it as a key to encrypt the password with AES.  The result is then salted with a unique salt and finally hashed with BCrypt.
3. The user's Display Name is set to their User ID (integer), as opposed to their Login Name, when the account is created.  The user can change it later, except it can not match anyone else's Display Name or too closely match a case-insensitive comparison to their Login Name.

   My question is, if the database were compromised, would this make it significantly harder to recover the passwords than storing plaintext usernames and uniquely salted and BRcypted passwords?

Comment: If your admin leaves and takes the database, then you can't change some of the security parameters. The exited admin will have the usernames, their passwords, and a method to recover them.

Comment: What security parameters are you referring to?  The salts as well as the hashed login names and passwords would all be stored right on the database the whole time.

Comment: How would the authentication look like?

Comment: 'code' string loginHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(loginName, SHARED_SALT);

            WidgetDataContext dc = new WidgetDataContext();
            var record = (from rec in dc.usp_GetUserByLoginName(loginHash)
                          select rec).SingleOrDefault();

            if (record == null)
                return new RequestResult("Invalid Login Name/Password");

            pwd = EncryptionServices.Encrypt(pwd, loginName);
            pwd = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pwd, record.Salt);

            if (pwd == record.Password)'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure appears to be very complicated. Actually you are adding a server side secret to the stored hashes (your procedure to hash passwords). That will indeed increase security, as long as the procedure stays secret. In other words, if the attacker has only read access to the database (SQL-injection) you have an advantage, as soon as he has got privileges on the server and knows the code, there is no advantage at all.

There is a much easier and safer way to get this advantage though. Just calculate a BCrypt hash with a random salt (most implementations will do that anyway), then encrypt this hash-value with a server-side key (AES for example). The key should not be derrived form other parameters, instead use a long and random enough key.

I tried to explain the reasons in my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php), maybe you want to have a look at it.

**Edit:**

Well i understand now, that you want to handle the login-name like a second password, and will not store it plaintext, instead you store only a BCrypt hash of it with a global "salt".

Lets assume that you are willing to spend 1 second of CPU time for password hashing. In your scheme you would have to split it to half a second for hashing the login-name and half a second for the password. An attacker has to brute-force the login-name first and the password in a second step.

1. Login-names are normally very weak passwords. While people are learning that passwords need to be strong, login-names often contain only a name with a number and are short.
2. You need to find the database record with the hash of the login-name, so you cannot use a random salt, instead you need to use a global "salt". This allows to build a single rainbow table to crack all usernames in one go. Important login-names like "admin" can be precalculated.
3. To avoid duplicates, you have to uppercase/lowercase the login-name, this reduces the search space even more.

That means you spend half a second for a very weak password (login-name), then half a second for the normal password. Compared to investing 1 second for the normal (hopefully strong) password, you are probably decreasing security, by all means i cannot see any advantage.

Comment: "Actually you are adding a server side secret to the stored hashes (your procedure to hash passwords)."

Comment: Database 1:  Username is salted with shared salt and BCrypted.  Password is encrypted with AES as UserName being encryption keythen salted with unique random salt and BCrypted.

  Database 2.  Username is plaintext.  Password is salted with unique salt and hashed with BCrypt.

  Assuming you knew how both databases were storing the UserName/Password and every single detail of the process was known in both cases, wouldn't it still be more difficult to recover the passwords with the first database?

Comment: @antelopecarbuilding395 - You gain very very little. If you use BCrypt as hashing algorithm, an attacker has to brute-force or to try a dictionary attack. BCrypt will protect the password in using much time per guess. Your first steps can be done once per user (using constant salt and username and bcrypt it) so they don't count. The encryption of the password before hashing, needs a little time, but you would invest it better in increasing the cost factor of BCrypt. Using the username can never be better than using a random salt and a strong independent key.

Comment: "Using the username can never be better than using a random salt and a strong independent key".

Comment: I am using a random salt and a per record independent key that itself is salted and hashed as a separate process and stored in the same database.  Also, the attacker better hope that every single username was recovered in his initial pass against the shared salted and hashed username list or else he would be trying to recover the uniquely salted and hashed cipher text with an unknown previous encryption key in regards to the usernames he couldn't recover.

Comment: In other words, I'm saying it might take 3 days instead of 3 hours to recover 11% of the passwords instead of 17% of the passwords without even changing the hashing algorithm or the number of passes.  The algorithm and number of passes could of course be changed independently.  The additional computational investment would be almost nothing for the defender and would be significantly greater for the attacker and would theoretically yield a modest reduction in gains event after the greater investment.

Comment: @antelopecarbuilding395 - Im sorry to disappoint you, but as i tried to explain, an attacker only has to modify his procedure for hashing passwords, and your additional steps do not increase the necessary time **per guess** significantly. Security by obscurity can be an advantage, but only as long as the procedure stays secret. You should think about exactly which problem you want to solve with what step (define a threat model). BCrypt slows down brute-forcing, random unique salt makes rainbow-tables impracticable, server-side key protects weak passwords in some cases.

Comment: "your additional steps do not increase the necessary time per guess"  With plaintext usernames, he can simply start guessing passwords. With salted and hashed usernames, he can not until he recovers the username.  Is it really that trivial time wise to recover literally all of 50,000 usernames that have been salted with a shared salt and BCrypted?  The ones you didn't recover, how would you recover the passwords?  What if someone's password was 123456, except their username was T67NrtFrwS09NmTM!@$lknMRF?  Also, I don't know where you get the idea that I've suggested keeping the process secret?

Comment: @antelopecarbuilding395 - Every decent security scheme should prepare for the worst (database stolen and procedure known). Brute-forcing is just clever guessing and trying today (search for hybrid-attack-mode). If your database is stolen, the username is known to the attacker, it is likely that hashes and username will be stolen together (same privileges necessary). Calculting the username-salt-hash can be done once per user, it isn't necessary to calculate it again for each guess, so it doesn't help much.

Comment: @antelopecarbuilding395 - If you encrypt the already calculated BCrypt-hash (see the tutorial) you have the advantage that you can exchange the server-side key (the global salt you mentioned). In your scheme the server-side key can never be exchanged, even if you know it leaked someway, because it was hashed as part of the password.

Comment: "If your database is stolen, the username is known to the attacker,"   The hash of the username would be known.  The plain-text of the username would not be stored ever.  The attacker would have to brute force every single username one at a time, not merely calculate its hash.  The hash of the username is useless to the attacker.  There is no secret pepper or secret encryption key that you have to worry about hiding.

Comment: @antelopecarbuilding395 - I understand now, that you do not want to store the login-name at all and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: "1.Login-names are normally very weak passwords. While people are learning that passwords need to be strong, login-names often contain only a name with a number and are short."

  I see my problem there.  I would be investing half my computation time trying to protect usernames like Rover17 instead of passwords like NkLjtG567F!T.  Even if the restrictions on the user name were heightened, the hashes would still be weakened by the shared salt.  Thanks for the taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @antelopecarbuilding395 - You are welcome, by the way, your username would make a strong password :-)

Answer (score 0):

The authentication code would look something like this.

```
public static LoginResult TryLogin(string loginName, string pwd)
    {
        string loginHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(loginName, SHARED_SALT);

        WidgetDataContext dc = new WidgetDataContext();
        var record = (from rec in dc.usp_GetUserByLoginName(loginHash)
                      select rec).SingleOrDefault();

        if (record == null)
            return new LoginResult(null, "Invalid Login Name/Password");

        if (record.FailedLoginCount >= MAX_CONSECUTIVE_LOGIN_FAILURES)
            return new LoginResult(null, "You have exceeded your maximum number of Login failures.  Your account is locked.");

        if (record.Locked) // In case account is locked for another reason
            return new LoginResult(null, "Your Account is locked.");

        pwd = EncryptionServices.Encrypt(pwd, loginName);
        pwd = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pwd, record.Salt);

        if (pwd == record.Password)
        {
            record.FailedLoginCount = 0;
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            return new LoginResult(record.UserId, "Login Successful");
        }

        record.FailedLoginCount++;
        dc.SubmitChanges();

        return new LoginResult(null, "Invalid Login Name/Password");
    }
```

Comment: Simply to clarify, I types the example up fairly quickly.  It is intended as a mock-up with lack of commenting, non-descriptive variable names (such as pwd instead of password), and is over-simplified in many ways.  I wanted to specify that and ask anyone looking at the code to take that into consideration.